# Why isn't supertab's <c-tab> binding working?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-supertab

There is the supertab binding `<c-tab>` that is supposed to produce a normal tab, but that doesn't work on my system (Mac; tried in iTerm and terminal).  And I just remembered reading that Tab is equivalent to `<c-i>`. Wouldn't that imply that `<c-tab>` ≡ `<c-c-i>` (≡ nonsense)? (I don't really need this binding, `<c-v><c-i>` is fine; but it got me curious.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about <kbd>tab</kbd> being the same same as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, as explained in [`:help key-codes`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#keycodes):

```
                    *key-notation* *key-codes* *keycodes*
These names for keys are used in the documentation.  They can also be used
with the ":map" command (insert the key name by pressing CTRL-K and then the
key you want the name for).

notation    meaning         equivalent  decimal value(s)    ~
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
<Nul>       zero            CTRL-@    0 (stored as 10) *<Nul>*
<BS>        backspace       CTRL-H    8 *backspace*
<Tab>       tab         CTRL-I    9 *tab* *Tab*
```

Following the procedure on [Vim FAQ "20.4. I am not able to create a mapping for the  key. What is wrong?"](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html) on my machine the output for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> differs from <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, both on terminal and gVim,

So Vim is able to map <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd> independently.
You could use the following mappings to check if your problem caused by some problem in Vim recognizing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> or in supertab plugin:

```
inoremap <c-tab> abc
inoremap <tab> def
```

Comment: From your answer I conclude that nothing can be done on my system. in iterm, c-tab produces nothing; in terminal, remapping tab also affects c-tab.